# Embedded Vimeo videos do not work on iPad Safari via ios simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, mobile-safari, vimeo

I have googled the heck out of this question, but I have found no information that is at all helpful. My question is simple: why can't I play embedded Vimeo videos (using the universal iframe embed code) on iOS Simulator running an iPad in Safari?

Is it because this is not supported on iOS Simulator, or is it a more complex problem? Thanks

Comment: Please describe what happens when you attempt to do so.  Also, it would be helpful if you post the embed code you're using.  It's also not clear from your question if you're trying to do this in a UIWebView or in an instance of Mobile Safari running in the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Vimeo embeds. I first noticed it in Safari on iPhone through the simulator. Then I tried it in Safari on the iPad (through the simulator). Finally, I tried just watching *any* video on the Vimeo site itself. None worked on the iPad/iPhone using the simulator. So I don't think the problem is specific to embeds, or any particular video. It's a problem with playing Vimeo videos in Safari on iOS, through the simulator, it seems.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer. I can't re-create the problem nowadays, but I think @Coleman was probably right that it was an issue with iOS simulator at the time of the posting.

Answer (score 0):

Is this universal to every vimeo video you encounter or only specific ones you are trying to embed? For example, if you visit vimeo.com on mobile safari are you able to play any of their videos in iOS simulator?

If you can play videos on Vimeo.com then the problem lies with the specific videos you're trying to embed. Certain Vimeo videos uploaded >2 years ago did not process well when Vimeo made the switch to HTML5. This is rectified be re-uploading the videos back into Vimeo and letting them re-process. Then use the new generated embed code.